# MRunit dependency latest in cloudera repository

Tags: mapreduce, repository, cloudera-cdh, mrunit

I could not find the latest `mrunit(1.1.0)` in *Cloudera repository*. The one available is `0.8.0-incubating`. Following is my `pom`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ma.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>MapReduce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.3.0-cdh5.1.2</hadoop.version>
        <hive.version>0.12.0-cdh5.1.2</hive.version>
        <mrunit.version>0.8.0-incubating</mrunit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- For unit testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>${mrunit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This is sufficient for all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Mapred</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-hadoop</id>
            <name>Hadoop Releases</name>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera-repos</id>
            <name>Cloudera Repos</name>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

if i change the version to 1.1.0 eclipse throws a artifact not found on the mrunit dependency in the pom file.

I tried adding apache repo

```
<id>central</id>
<url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
<repository>
```

*Eclipse* downloads the jar in the `.m2` but I still get the artifact not found. An the unit test call will not compile.
Can someone please help what is the safe way to use latest `mrunit` with cloudera repo.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: me too, the same status

Comment: had the same in Idea, and brucenan answer fix me this issue, you should accept it's answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `mrunit`dependancy declaration:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
   <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
   <version>${mrunit.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You should add `<classifier>hadoop2</classifier>`to *clarify which version hadoop you want to use*, the classifier value is hadoop1 or hadoop2.

So you need to change `pom.xml`dependancy to this since you use *Hadoop 2.X*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>${mrunit.version}</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
```